# Unable to build my project because of Icon issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am running Xcode 4.3.2. I am trying to build my project for archiving but I have been unable to figure out how to get the icons working.  My initial goal is to just get it to build - I don't care if I have pretty icons at this point.  This is a universal app.

There is a lot of information out there on the Internet about editing your plist manually and I see in Summary there are places to define your icons, but none of it is working for me.

```
warning: Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: Icon.png (-19007)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: Info.plist: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found.  You must define CFBundleIcons, CFBundleIconFiles, CFBundleIconFile, or provide a default Icon.png that is 57x57 (-19013)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

warning: iPad: Info.plist: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found.  You must define CFBundleIcons, CFBundleIconFiles, CFBundleIconFile, or provide a default Icon-72.png that is 72x72 (-19013)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have this in your info.plist

[image]

Change it to this.

[image]

**EDIT:** Give it another try dragging your icon files from "Resources" directly to here...
When it says it would like to copy them select YES.

[image]

Comment: What is the minimum set of icons I can get away with?

Comment: Well that depends, if you aren't planning on supporting iPad, then you CAN stick with just the iPhone icons. However, for the sake of user experience, I recommend you include as many as you are able.

Comment: I have updated my plist to look exactly as you specify. I also have the Icon.png and Icon@2x.png files in my "Resources" group in my project. I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: I tried that too - no luck. I am shocked Apple was able to make something that should be so simple so complicated.

Comment: After lots of time spent, it is now working. I don't know how to make it work, just keep trying.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. It's frustrating because the files that it says don't exist do, in fact exist. I tried this drag idea and got a message, 'The file "/../Icon.png" already exists in your project, but the launch image must have the name "Icon.png". The file will be copied and added to your project as "Icon.png". Do you want to continue?' So I click Yes, and there is no change. The only thing I wonder about is that there is a space in the path. Is that an issue?

Comment: @VictorEngel I've had that happen before. Usually you can just navigate to the projects bundle in Finder, and delete the files. Then they'll be _red_ in Xcode. Delete them from there and try re-adding again.

Comment: I'll try that. Interestingly, the little icon in the navigator next to these files changes between A and D, seemingly randomly. If I click a file, the icon is displayed. But some of the indicators may change between A and D or vice versa. Weird. There was no problem with ad-hoc distribution (the icons appeared appropriately). This is only happening with app store distribution.

Comment: The original answer given (copying to the icon box) did not work. Your comment above did (deleting files and copying them back in). If I upvote, it looks like the original answer is what made it work. So I'll let me comment be the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

For me the fix was to delete all icon related entries in the Info.plist file, and then use the GUI in 0x7fffffff's screenshot to re-create the Info.plist entries.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from NSPostWhenIdle's answer, I needed to add CFBundleIconFile ('Icon file'. Not 'Icon files'.) in the plist.

On Xcode 4.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the icon files from your app folder, remove the Icon files line from info.plist.

Then drag the icon file (from another directory which is not your project folder) to the xcode App icons UI.

Clean => Build and Run.